# Custom icon and default current location icon on Map when needed in iPhone

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, currentlocation

I have an application where in I give user 2 options.
1. Select your current location through GPS
2. Enter your current location manually.

What I want is When user has selected thh first option then I have to display the blue animated icon for current location
And when user has selected 2nd option then I have to display my own custom icon for current location.

Is it possible? Suggestions are most welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set a boolean variable for Example isInGPSMode

now apply following code

```
if(isInGPSMode==TRUE)
{
     mapViewHome.showsUserLocation=TRUE;
}
else
{
     mapViewHome.showsUserLocation=FALSE;
}
```

and handle the map view delegate as

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    if(annotation==mapViewHome.userLocation)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    addAnnonation *tempAnnonation=(addAnnonation *)annotation;

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    return annView;

}
```

for further details refer the link
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html

hope this helps

Comment: If I zoom out my map.. The default current location icon disappears. and If I again tap on the button that takes the coordinates from GPS and zooms the map to that particular location then the default current location icon appears after near about 3-4 minutes.. Any idea what the problem can be?? Or is it default behaviour..

Answer (score 1):

Rupesh's solution in Swift :

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    // Keep default pin for user location
    if myMapView.userLocation.isEqual(annotation) {
        return nil;
    }

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("pin") as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
        pinView!.pinColor = .Red
    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }
    return pinView
}
```